# How to display localStorage values on jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, local-storage

In javascript function: stored value in localStorage using this line

```
localStorage.setItem("Phrase","Hello Tech");
```

And want to display Phrase's value in jsp file:

```
localStorage.getItem("Phrase");
```

But it's showing me this full sentence, not a value of it.
Could anyone help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry It was typo in this line. I wrote it as in jsp file: localStorage.getItem("Phrase");

Comment: Hi, can you add the code from the JSP and the JS files?

Comment: Please attach some more code to get idea what you are missing .and make sure that localStorage is browser dependent . some times you won't get exact data if you are passing value as dynamic .

Answer (score 2):

You have to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

The `localStorage` is browser-side thing, JSP has no access to it. I.e. in JSP you can only generate JS code to access `localStorage`, but this code will be executed by the browser.